# How do I create a local mail account?

Tags: debian, email, exim

I want to create a local mail account suitable for [apt-listchanges](https://packages.debian.org/stable/apt-listchanges). In other words, local services will send mail to `local@localhost` (?) and I should be able to check that mailbox using a regular mail client (Thunderbird, Geany...)

This would preferably be a "system" account rather than a "user" account, but if userland apps can't access that, a "user" account will do.

Answer (score 3):

On a Debian-based system you should already have `exim4` which provides the `sendmail` utility. Configure it as follows:

**1. Confirm FQDN**

exim4 requires a "fully qualified" domain name for your local machine, which just means it needs a dot in it. Confirm this with the following:

```
$ hostname
$ hostname --fqdn
```

These will return your machine name and your FQDN. By default your FQDN is exactly the same as your machine name and does not contain a dot, and you need to change it.

(If it is different and contains a dot, skip step 2.)

**2. Modify hosts file**

We will now set your FQDN. To do this modify your `hosts` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

You should see the following lines in the file (gaps are tabs):

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.1    HOSTNAME
```

change this to...

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.1    mail.localhost    HOSTNAME
```

...then save and exit. Repeat step one to confirm that your hostname remains the same, and your FQDN has been updated.

**3. Configure exim4**

Configure exim4 as follows:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

In the questions that follow select the following options (and otherwise select the defaults):

- "local delivery only; not on a network"
- System mail name: "mail.localhost"
- Other destinations for which mail is accepted: "mail.localhost"
- Keep number of DNS queries minimal? Yes
- Delivery method: mbox format in /var/mail
- Where to send `root` and `postmaster` mail: `USERNAME@localhost`

  - Now system messages will be sent to your user account and you don't need special permissions to access them

**4. Test**

To test, you can send a local email with mail USERNAME@localhost. Fill in the prompts as follows

```
$ mail USERNAME@localhost
Cc: <leave blank, hit enter>
Subject: test subject
test body <hit enter>
<hit Ctrl-D>
```

You can confirm the message has been received by typing `mail`. Hit Q to quit the text-based mail client.

**5. Configure MUA GUI**

[Now configure your preferred GUI client for mbox access](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427136), and check that your test message also appears in your inbox there.

Comment: I wonder whether this works for sending mails to the root user as well? Currently I can't send mail from a user other than the root user to the root user (but it works for another purpose I mainly needed it for).

Comment: Note that a default desktop install of Ubuntu 18.04 does _not_ come with `exim` installed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by *system* and *user*
accounts but if you're asking how to handle local e-mail on `Linux`
it's quite simple.  I don't use `Ubuntu` on the daily basis but I've
just run the following in the virtual machine:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

`sendmail` is the name of the `SMTP` server that will deliver e-mails.

```
$ sudo apt-get install mutt
```

`mutt` is the name of the `Mail User Agent` that we'll use to read mail.

Make sure that `sendmail` is running:

```
$ ps aux | grep '[s]endmail'
root     31687  0.0  0.1 108964  5408 ?        Ss   19:24   0:00 sendmail: MTA: accepting connections
```

Send a test e-mail to yourself:

```
$ sendmail -i $(whoami) <<MAIL_END
> Subject: test e-mail
>
> HELLO
> MAIL_END
```

Note that after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> you get:

`You have new mail in /var/mail/<USERNAME>`

Use `mutt` to read mail, for example:

```
$ mutt -f /var/mail/ja
```

Actually, when using `mutt` you don't even have to use `-f`:

```
$ mutt
```

is enough as `mutt` will try to open `$MAIL`.  In `Ubuntu` it's defined by default:

```
$ echo $MAIL
/var/mail/ja
```